# Server 2012- Installed DNS Role but DNS Manager not showing up in Tools

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, windows

I have a Windows Server 2012 (In Virtual Box) setup with a DNS Role. In the server manager, DNS shows up on the left hand selection. However, DNS does not show up in the Tools.

[image]

Comment: I am fairly new to this Server. Sorry if it is something simple or if this is posted in the wrong place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install DNS Manager separately.
It's under:

- Features

  - Remote Server Administration Tools

    - Role Administration Tools

      - DNS Server Tools